# How to keep the best shot of an object with an Object detection model over a video

Tags: machine-learning, python, object-detection

I’m pretty new to Machine learning and stuff. I’m going to start to work on a project, I have a background with code. My goal is to collect data from my city roads and build a strong dataset for people to use it.
At the moment, i have a kinda working solution, my ML model (using yolov7 https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7 + Python) is able to detect cars and license-plate. I implemented a way to crop cars from from a video stream BUT it’s cropping every single frame where there’s a “car” detected.
[image: batch of cropped images from a video that i found on youtube]

I found a website of a company showing how their solution works “https://www.sighthound.com/” and we can see on the video presentation (~0.6s into the video) [image: what i want my project to do]

It’s exactly what i want to acheive, which is to keep the best result of all my cropped images from a batch and use it to create a dataset.

Do i have to put some kind of “ID” over the “car” label (like an object tracking) to identify each unique cars passing in my stream, and after that, use some kind of machine learning algorithm to select the best looking cropped images for each batch of images of a unique car ? Or there’s better solution?

Ps : I'm not doing OCR or surveillance, My only goal with this project it to create an open and free dataset for my community to use.

**Update :**

I want this dataset to be useable in a large quantity of sub-project and maybe inspired people to create their own dataset and contribute to the community.
So by "best" i mean : Less noise, less blur, the object "car" can be seen in its fullest, a clear view of the object "lience-plate".

[image: example of "Best shot"]

For context, the country where i live is very unique (multiple gouvernment making the laws, we're a hub a population), we have 5~6 different type license plate in circulation, and little to no information about the what's going on the road.
I want to provide a high quality dataset to the community and help people/students/whoever want to work on a solution to fix road problems :

- Analyse who's using the road (country 1: 50%, country 2: 25%, country 3: 25%), ...

Comment: Maybe it would help if you further defined what you mean by "best". Is "best" defined as the most complete picture of the vehicle? So any vehicle with the bottom or top cutoff is worse than the entire picture, or is "best" defined as the car having more pixels?

Comment: I think that @juicedatom is exactly right.  There are an infinite number of ways to contrive "best" and many of them contradict.  A "best" for shortest time between start and stop is the opposite of "least energy" or "least max force" between stops.  If you can get exactingly precise, the definition can lead straight to the formulation you wish you had.

Comment: I updated the post, but basically, I want to build a high quality dataset from a video-stream of a camera on the road. So i want to keep only 1 picture of every car that i capture in the video. By "Best" i mean, the image where the object "car" and/or object "license-plate" is visible in their fullest with mininum blur and noise (as clear as possible).
PS: by "High quality" i don't mean 4K, but highly reusable. Maybe OCR on license-plate, licence-plate recognition for parking (we have many different plate), car statistics (want kind of car are on the road), and so on..